# No transformation when adding revolute joints to URDF

Tags: urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am trying to recreate the Doosan A0509 Collaborative robot in ROS2, as part of me trying to learn ROS2 as well as how I would approach a general problem of this type*(creating a robot in ROS, and then control it)*. My goals from this project are presented as follows:

To be able to take the robot design files provided in the doosan-robots repository, and recreate them to be able to visualise the robot in Rviz2.

1. To be able to control the robot using the simple joint_state_publisher_gui.
2. To be able to control the robot
   using MoveIt2.

I have tried to study the urdf file provided under the doosan-robots repository to be able to understand how it was written, and am currently trying to do the same in [my repository](http://github.com/sampreets3/dsr_a0509_description), so that I can at least visualise the robot using Rviz2. I am facing a couple of problems with the first step, and I would love to know from you guys how I can go about solving my problem. The detailed description of the issue is given below.

**Description of Issue:**

I am able to visulalize the entire robot only when I use "fixed" joints. Any other joint type(I tried revolute and continuous) causes the particular child link to arrive at the origin and the error message "No transformation from elbow_link to shoulder_link", in the example scenario where the joint was between links "shoulder_link" and "elbow_link".

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong, since I am basing my understanding of the URDF mostly from the URDF tutorials from ROS2.

Hardware and Software Information:

Ubuntu 20.04

ROS2 Foxy, installed from debian packages as per instructions from here.

I can add any extra information that might be useful for this scenario, just let me know in the comments.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389427/no-transformation-when-adding-revolute-joints-to-urdf/) by [sampreets3](https://answers.ros.org/users/87884/sampreets3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 230 on 2021-10-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are several bugs in your package. Mainly, you aren't launching any `joint_state_publisher` or `joint_state_publisher_gui` when the parameter `gui` is `true`. Because of this, there is no `joint_states` topic. This is fine when there are only fixed joints, but it leads to the error you described when there are revolute joints.

Here's a patch that fixes your package:

```
From 4ea19497bc9eace4eb3fdee135073f80cfc95c44 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: =?UTF-8?q?Martin=20G=C3=BCnther?= <martin.guenther at dfki.de>
Date: Wed, 27 Oct 2021 10:10:56 +0200
Subject: [PATCH 1/1] Fix several small bugs

* the "meshes" directory was not installed
* the joint_state_publisher GUI was not launched when the argument "gui"
  was true (default)
* there was a unused launch argument "use_sim_time"
* the package.xml package name for rviz2 was incorrect, so rosdep didn't
  work
---
 CMakeLists.txt           |  2 +-
 launch/display.launch.py | 12 +++++++++---
 package.xml              |  2 +-
 rviz/urdf_config.rviz    |  2 +-
 4 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)

diff --git a/CMakeLists.txt b/CMakeLists.txt
index 0595210..f3649e1 100644
--- a/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -22,7 +22,7 @@ find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
 # find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)
 
 install(
-  DIRECTORY src launch rviz 
+  DIRECTORY src launch meshes rviz 
   DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
 )
 
diff --git a/launch/display.launch.py b/launch/display.launch.py
index 1618237..248f559 100644
--- a/launch/display.launch.py
+++ b/launch/display.launch.py
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ import os
 
 def generate_launch_description():
     pkg_share = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='dsr_a0509_description').find('dsr_a0509_description')
-    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/a0509.blue.urdf')
+    default_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'src/description/robot_a0509.urdf')
     default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/urdf_config.rviz')
     
     robot_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
@@ -20,6 +20,13 @@ def generate_launch_description():
         name='joint_state_publisher',
         condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
     )
+
+    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
+        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
+        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
+        name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
+        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
+    )
     
     rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
         package='rviz2',
@@ -36,10 +43,9 @@ def generate_launch_description():
                                             description='Absolute path to robot urdf file'),
         launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='rvizconfig', default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
                                             description='Absolute path to rviz config file'),
-        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='True',
-                                            description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),
        
         joint_state_publisher_node,
+        joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
         robot_state_publisher_node,
         rviz_node
     ])
diff --git a/package.xml b/package.xml
index 85a48ef..fa23519 100644
--- a/package.xml
+++ b/package.xml
@@ -12,7 +12,7 @@
   <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher</exec_depend>
   <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher_gui</exec_depend>
   <exec_depend>robot_state_publisher</exec_depend>
-  <exec_depend>rviz</exec_depend>
+  <exec_depend>rviz2</exec_depend>
   <exec_depend>xacro</exec_depend>
 
   <export>
diff --git a/rviz/urdf_config.rviz b/rviz/urdf_config.rviz
index b542f86..57ed1e1 100644
--- a/rviz/urdf_config.rviz
+++ b/rviz/urdf_config.rviz
@@ -133,7 +133,7 @@ Visualization Manager:
   Enabled: true
   Global Options:
     Background Color: 48; 48; 48
-    Fixed Frame: base_link
+    Fixed Frame: base
     Frame Rate: 30
   Name: root
   Tools:
-- 
2.25.1
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2021-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-27**:
Awesome answer. Love the idea of showing the changes in code.

**Comment by [sampreets3](https://answers.ros.org/users/87884/sampreets3/) on 2021-10-27**:
Hello @martin-gunther, thank you so much for your detailed response. I was able to understand the mistakes I made by studying your patch. I was able to solve my problem using this as well.

Thanks again!